# Rails how to response JSON in ISO-8859-1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want my app to response with body utf-8 and iso-8859-1 encoded
per requests with Accept-Charset="utf-8" or Accept-Charset="iso-8859-1".
The response body is always JSON.

In my controller, when I doing this

```
render(json: data, status: :created)
```

It response with Content-Type="application/json; charset=utf-8" as well.

But how to make a response with body iso-8859-1 encoded when request Accept-Charset="iso-8859-1"?

Answer (score 1):

In  order to do this, you can use the method `force_encoding` and `encoding` for example

```
data = {'name'=>'raghav'}.to_json
data.encoding  #This would return what encoding the value as #<Encoding:UTF-8>
new_data = data.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1') #This would force the encoding
new_data.encoding  #<Encoding:ISO-8859-1>
```

Also to do this on the specific case you can always read the `request.headers` hash to determine the encoding.

There is also another method called `encode` the  main difference between these are `force_encoding` changes the way string is being read from bytes, and `encode` changes the way string is written without changing the output (if possible)